# OSM tile server: Arabic fonts are not displaying

Tags: openstreetmap, font, tile-server

I installed OSM tile server with a whole planet. All the fonts are displaying except for Arabic countries. Although my font directory has some Arabic fonts too. How to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: but does the font you are using actually have Arabic symbols?